# cannot load cl-lib at emacs startup

Tags: emacs

I have downloaded autopair from Github and extracted it to `~/.emacs.d` . Also I added the lines given in the installation instructions

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/autopair") ;; comment if autopair.el is in standard load path 
(require 'autopair)
(autopair-global-mode) ;; enable autopair in all buffers
```

I modified `(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/autopair")` as `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/autopair-master/")` as that folder contains the autopair.el file. But when I open emacs it shows

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/karthikeyan/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, cl-lib
```

I use emacs 23.4.1 in Linux Mint 15 and is there any alternate way to autocomplete the braces with a function at startup? . Also it doesn't showup autopair mode in `Meta-x`

Comment: I suspect you need to either upgrade to Emacs 24.3, or [download and install cl-lib](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/cl-lib.html).

Comment: I upgraded just now and removed emacs 23 . But it still gets displayed in menu. How can I remove it from appearing in menu? @legoscia

Comment: legoscia: You should post that as an answer so that it can be accepted. (I didn't even know that forward compatibility package existed; that's definitely useful information.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try this (my emacs version is 23):

1. create new directory **cl-lib** in your **.emacs.d** directory
2. put [this file](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/emacs-lisp/cl-lib.el) into this **cl-lib** directory
3. add at top of your .emacs file these strings:

   - (add-to-list 'load-path "/path_to_your.emacs.d/cl-lib/")
   - (require 'cl-lib)

Comment: That link is dead. :(

Comment: I'm using 23.4 and after adding cl-lib to load path I get `Symbol's function definition is void: gv-define-simple-setter`